# Prepared statement with PHP and MySQL without using mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I'd like to know if it is possible to create a prepared statement with PHP and MySQL using the mysql library rather than the mysqli library.

I can't find anything on the PHP documentation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PHP documentation [quite clearly states](http://php.net/mysqli.overview) (at the end of that page) that the [`mysql` extension](http://php.net/book.mysql) does *not* support prepared statements. An alternative to [`mysqli`](http://php.net/book.mysqli) that supports prepared statements would be [`PDO_MYSQL`](http://php.net/ref.pdo-mysql).

Answer (score 3):

what about [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) ?

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score -1):

Why do you want to use a Prepared Statement?

If SQL injection is your concern you could always roll your own:

```
$fname = "Robert'); DROP TABLE students;--";
$lname = "Smith";

$pureSql = "SELECT FROM `users` WHERE `fname` = '$fname'   AND `lname` = '$lname'";
$prepSql = "SELECT FROM `users` WHERE `fname` = :userfname AND `lname` = :userlname";

echo $pureSql, "\n";
echo prepare($prepSql, array('userfname' => $fname, 'userlname' => $lname)), "\n";

function prepare($sql, $params=array()){

    if(strlen($sql) < 2 || count($params) < 1){
        return $sql;
    }

    preg_match_all('/\:[a-zA-Z0-9]+/', $sql, $matches);

    $safeSql = $sql;
    foreach($matches[0] as $arg){
        if(array_key_exists(ltrim($arg, ':'), $params)){
            $safeSql = str_replace($arg, "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($params[ltrim($arg, ':')]) . "'", $safeSql);
        }
    }

    return $safeSql;

} //prepare()
```

Output is:

SELECT FROM `users` WHERE `fname` = 'Robert'); DROP TABLE students;--'   AND `lname` = 'Smith'
SELECT FROM `users` WHERE `fname` = 'Robert\'); DROP TABLE students;--' AND `lname` = 'Smith'

EDIT: forgot the xkcd link http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: nice idea. however, this a) still doesn't let us access server-side Prepared Statements, and b) has bugs (e.g. int parameters (`1`) get quoted (`'1'`), which might lead to problems with strict sql). i guess it's not so trivial to write a bug free `prepare()`.

Comment: Simply replacing quotes doesn't actually prevent exploitation. Please DO NOT ATTEMPT THIS unless you REALLY know what you are doing (e.g. you are Monty).

Comment: Sounds like good advice but I need proof to be sure. Show us an exploit that exposes the vulnerability in this code.